# Virtual GPU for Ubuntu 16.04 Clients on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, performance, gpu

Assuming the host OS has a GPU, can anybody tell me if Ubuntu 16.04 clients run using VirtualBox will be able to make use of the GPU through virtualization?

I read that GPU virtualization is only useful for QEMU, but I heard VirtualBox is based (partially?) on QEMU so will I see performance benefits?  Also, does it matter what the host OS is?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can. You have to enable it, through. VirtualBox VM Settings->Display, check "Enable 3D Acceleration" and "Enable 2D Video Acceleration" on the screen tab. (And if you haven't set the Video Memory up to 128MB here yet, do so)

This allows the guest to directly use the host's GPU for OpenGL and Direct3D, instead of emulating it.

This should work on all hosts that are themselves able to use the GPU in question.